# Conditionally display results by key

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Given the following sample data, I need to display the results by type:

```
{
    "count": 50,
    "data": [{
        "id": "title",
        "image": "https://url-to-image.jpg",
        "permalink": "/folder/bob/",
        "text": "lots of text",
        "title": "Bob",
        "type": "User"
    }, {
        "id": "title2",
        "image": "https://url-to-image2.jpg",
        "permalink": "/folder/joe/",
        "text": "lots of text here",
        "title": "Joe",
        "type": "Article"
    }, {
        "id": "title3",
        "image": "https://url-to-image3.jpg",
        "permalink": "/attorneys/jim/",
        "text": "lots of text here",
        "title": "Jim",
        "type": "Blog"
    }]
}
```

I'm trying to run a condition that if the type is a certain one, to display those posts:

```
$("#searchterm").keyup(function(e) {
   var q = $("#searchterm").val();
   //Only begin search with at least 3 characters.
   if(q.length > 3){
      ajax_search();
   }
   //Send search query
   function ajax_search(){
   $.getJSON("http://url-to-search?q=" + q, {
            dataType:'jsonp'
     },
     //Get results and make 'em look good
     function(data) {
       console.log(data);
       $(".results").empty();
      //  $(".results").append("Results for <b> " + q + "</b>");
         $.each(data.data, function(i, data) {
                     if(data.type === 'Article'){
             $(".articles").append("<li><a href=localhost:4000" + data.permalink + ">" + data.title + "</a></li>");
                     } else if(data.type === 'Blog'){
                         $(".blog").append("<li><a href=localhost:4000" + data.permalink + ">" + data.title + "</a></li>");
                     }
         });
      });
    }
});
```

However, the results come up empty, although there are results without the conditional statements.

In the end, the results should look like this:

**Article**

Joe

**Blog**

Jim

Comment: Probably not the problem, but it's generally a bad idea to use the the same name for parameters in nested functions (`data`, in your case). Also, you're defining a function inside an event handler; this will cause that function to be redefined on every keyup, which is likely not what you want.

Comment: I guess the more direct way of asking the question is, how can I fix my `if/else` conditional to check the `type` of each object in the data array and display the results based on that.

Comment: You can use `$.grep` method to filter those results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the issue is with an overflow I have set to be able to scroll through results was set to the wrong class.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this:

```js
var result = {
    "count": 50,
    "data": [{
        "id": "title",
        "image": "https://url-to-image.jpg",
        "permalink": "/folder/bob/",
        "text": "lots of text",
        "title": "Bob",
        "type": "User"
    }, {
        "id": "title2",
        "image": "https://url-to-image2.jpg",
        "permalink": "/folder/joe/",
        "text": "lots of text here",
        "title": "Joe",
        "type": "Article"
    }, {
        "id": "title3",
        "image": "https://url-to-image3.jpg",
        "permalink": "/attorneys/jim/",
        "text": "lots of text here",
        "title": "Jim",
        "type": "Blog"
    }]
};

var filteredView = function(data,type,divclass){
  var filteredResults = $.grep(data, function(d){ return d.type == type; });
  var container = $("<div class='"+divclass+"'></div>").appendTo("#results");
  for(i in filteredResults){
     container.append("<div><h3>" + filteredResults[i].title + "</h3><p>" + filteredResults[i].text + "</p></div>");
  }
};

filteredView(result["data"],"Article","article");
filteredView(result["data"],"Blog","blog");
filteredView(result["data"],"User","user");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: That's close, but I'm looking for a way to loop through with my original script and based on the `data.type`, append the results to each of the types based on existing classes. So `if(data.type == "Article")`, only results with type article will be appended to an `<div class="article"></div>` div.

Comment: This will do what you want with a single modification. I'll show you how.